# How would I stack these divs?

Tags: html, css

I need to stack these divs on top of each other, but I dont know how to, is it possible to do so or would i need to redo my code and make it simplier?
The divs, jant1 and jant2 will be hidden, but they need to be ontop of each other otherwise jant2 when visible will be underneath the invisible jant1
HTML:

```
<div class="times">
    <div class="janT1">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1" data-title="January 1st">01:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">02:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">03:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">04:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">05:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">06:00</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="times">
    <div class="janT2">
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2"</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">02:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">03:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">04:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">05:00</a></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col">
            <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">06:00</a></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.times {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    padding-top:5%;
}

.janT1, .janT2 {
    position:relative;
    text-align: justify;
    min-width: 412px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 99.8%; /* it changes by screen size actually */
    background-color:white;
    font-size:34px;
    object:none;
}

.janT1:after, .janT2:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.col1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.box1 {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: What does “hiding” the elements mean exactly here? If you use `display:none` for that, then they are completely removed from the flow, so your problem would be – well, non-existent :)

Comment: I think it may be just a problem in my script :<script>
        $(function () {
            $('.janT1, .janT2').hide();
            $('.rowstuff1 .col .box1 .jan1').on('click', function () {
                        $('.rowstuff1,.times .janT1').toggle();
                    }
            );
        });
    </script>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the `.times` div around both times, set its `position: relative`, then set the `.jan1, .jan2` styles to `position: absolute`. This will lay them right over top one another.

Additionally, I've added a `.hidden` class so you can easily hide each div for testing in the snippet below.

```css
.times {
    height:100%;
    width:100%;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    margin:auto;
    padding-top:5%;
    position:relative;
}

.janT1, .janT2 {
    position:absolute;
    text-align: justify;
    min-width: 412px;
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 99.8%; /* it changes by screen size actually */
    background-color:white;
    font-size:34px;
    object:none;
}

.janT1:after, .janT2:after {
    content: '';
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100%;
}

.col1 {
    display: inline-block;
}
.box1 {
    border: 1px solid white;
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color:white;
}

.hidden {display:none}
```

```html
<div class="times">
  <div class="janT1 hidden">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1" data-title="January 1st">01:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">02:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">03:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">04:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">05:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan1">06:00</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="janT2">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">99:99</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">02:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">03:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">04:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">05:00</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
        <div class="box2"><a href="img/pic.png" data-lightbox="jan2">06:00</a></div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Im not sure if I understand exactly what you want. But your code currently displays both janT1 and janT2 divs stacked. But because your height is set to 100% you have to scroll down to see the second div. If you remove `height:100%` from the `.times` class, janT1 will be right ontop of janT2.

And then to hide it you could use one of the two below:

`display:none`
if you want the div to disappear and everything else on the page to flow in its spot.

`visibility:hidden`
if you want the div to not be visible but still maintain an empty spot on the page so other elements can not move into its position.

However, if you meant stacked as ontop of each other, instead of above each other, then you will need to use the z-index property, and ensure you have `display:inline` property.